# Vim doesn't use default indenting for markdown

Tags: indentation

My default indent width settings (4 spaces) are not used for markdown files. Whenever I open a markdown file it is indented using 2 spaces.

Here are my default indent width settings. In my `.vim/vimrc` I have

```
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

almost at the end. I have no markdown plugins installed.

I have a `.vim/ftdetect/markdown.vim`

```
au BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.md set filetype=markdown
```

and a `.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim`

```
let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['python', 'bash=sh', 'shell=sh', 'c', 'html', 'css', 'javascript', 'js=javascript', 'json=javascript' ]
let g:markdown_syntax_conceal = 0
let g:markdown_minlines = 100
setlocal spell
```

Also adding

```
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

to `.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim` does not change the situation.

Note, the filetype is properly recognized. Manually setting it after the file is opened worked.

- Why are my settings not applied?
- How to debug this?

Comment: I know this isn't *exactly* what you asked, but does this answer your question? [How to find what is causing the command line height to be changed after opening / closing a tab?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5727/how-to-find-what-is-causing-the-command-line-height-to-be-changed-after-opening)

Comment: `:verbose set tabstop? softtabstop? shiftwidth? expandtab?`

Comment: pls explain how exactly default settings are not used

Comment: @MaximKim your posted command shows that the wrong settings come from my `.vim/ftplugin/html.vim`. This file only holds the 4 commands.

Comment: @Stefan markdown sources html, so double-check that. In general, you want to use `.vim/after/ftplugin` and `setlocal`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble the html sourcing was indeed the issue. With @MaximKim 's answer I can understand why `.vim/after/ftplugin` is preferred. Would you mind commenting on why `setlocal` should be used over `set`?

Comment: @Stefan I'd recommend reading `:help :setlocal` and `:help ftplugin` (search for the heading `OPTIONS`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open `:e $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/markdown.vim` you will find that it loads ALL filetype plugins for html

```
runtime! ftplugin/html.vim ftplugin/html_*.vim ftplugin/html/*.vim
```

Command `runtime!` with an exclamation mark will source all matched files found in your runtime path, including your local `.vim/ftplugin/html.vim`.

To properly override any settings you have to put them into `.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` file -- it will be sourced AFTER `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/markdown.vim` and `.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim` (and thus after your html included filetypes).